# AngularJs index.html does not recognize German locale script

Tags: angularjs, locale

My index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-i18n/angular-locale_de-de.js"></script>


<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="costCtrl">

<h1>Price: {{ price | currency}}</h1>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('costCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.price = 58;
});
</script>


<p>The currency filter formats a number to a currency format.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

does not show the Euro sign behind the value as it is supposed to be. I tried also to install angular dynamic locale through bower but to no avail. I am on a Ubuntu 16.04. LTS machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working snippet you can try to run with a CDN of german locale that displays the euro currency sign.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.6.4/angular-locale_de-de.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="costCtrl">
    <h1>Price: {{ price | currency}}</h1>
  </div>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('costCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.price = 58;
    });
  </script>

  <p>The currency filter formats a number to a currency format.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Since this is working, I assume you have a **wrong path**: `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-i18n/angular-locale_de-de.js`

Comment: Thanks, this works, but any ideas as to why the other does not? It is definitely there.

Comment: depends where your root folder is at (where `index.html` is located). Try: `usr/local/...`, `./usr/local/...`, `../usr/local/...` variations. Maybe there is another folder that you missed: `some_folder/usr/local/...` or `usr/some_folder/local/...`

Comment: It seems the problem is that I cannot access any file outside of the directory index.html is located in, because it works if I put it there, but it does not if I put it in my home folder. Is this normal?

Comment: I don't know your file structure to say for sure. Do you get any errors in the console (404 errors perhaps)?

Comment: I am sorry, I got the answer. I have a node server running on port 3000 and it points at the folder the index.html file is in. Obviously, I cannot get to files outside of this framework with a relative path. If I run the index.html file independently, it works.

Comment: Thanks so much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using npm or bower install the [angular-i18n](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-i18n) package.

Otherwise, add this to the html.

```
<script src="i18n/angular-locale_de-de.js"></script>
```

Now default currency type should be euro.

Comment: I have installed it globally, which is where the fourth line of my code is pointing at.

Comment: @PaulRousseau it's not pointing correctly, putting a CDN works: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.6.4/angular-locale_de-de.js"></script>`